# What features of HTML5 will only work with Chrome?

Tags: html, firefox, google-chrome

Every now and then our boss issues a Developer Challenge competition. He challenges us to do something with a new technology and whoever does the best wins a small prize. It's Just a bit of fun.

This time the challenge is to do something with HTML5. One of the requirements is that is has to work *only* in Chrome. I don't think this is a realistic requirement though, because I thought Firefox 6 & Chrome were pretty much on par with each other?

Are there any features of HTML5 that will work only in Chrome?

Comment: Use the [`<details>` and `<summary>`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=detail) HTML element, along with an [infinite progress meter](http://caniuse.com/#feat=progressmeters). Job done. (http://caniuse.com/#cats=HTML5).

Answer (score 1):

Check this link http://html5test.com/results.html with Chrome.

**Update:**
I find this usefull link with compatibility tables for support of HTML5, CSS3, SVG and more: [When can I use...](http://caniuse.com)

Comment: How will that tell him the HTML5 features which don't work in any other browser?

Comment: There is a link at the bottom where you can get the test results of different browser. A score of 0 means that the browser did't pass the test so it hasn't that feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [FileWriter API](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-writer-api/). While there is a bunch of browsers implementing the File API, I think that only Chrome allows writing files (see http://caniuse.com/#search=filewriter).

caniuse.com lists other HTML5-features as well that are supposedly exclusive to Chrome right now, e.g. [web notifications](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/notifications/quick/) and [`<details>` tag](http://html5doctor.com/summary-figcaption-element/).

Answer (score 0):

[NaCl](http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/wiki/NativeClientInGoogleChrome): Google's take on ActiveX. Have fun.